# CANNOT change anythings in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why can I not change the color, size or anything by using the `project` class or `project` id?? I can only can change something through `These` CLASS??

```css
.These {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 90vh;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#project {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="These">
  <p clsss="project" id="project">
    These are some of my projects
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo ... "clsss"

Comment: WHen i use #project i can change the colour and other things, but I cannot change it when using the .project.

Comment: Read my first comment.

Comment: OH SORRY I am SO STUPID

Comment: Vote to close for typo

Comment: I AM new to code. I have one more question can we use some software to avoid the typo problem when we are coding ??

Comment: As an extension. Also typically the class and id have different names for styling multiple elements. To style all the elements of a class use .{}  and #{} in CSS.

Comment: @SMARTTOM Some editors such as Visual Studio Code and Atom among others have auto-complete/suggestions that help avoid typos. Welcome to the world of coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check and make sure your CSS style sheet is properly linked to your HTML.
Your code works for me in codepen.There is a typo, however the ID should still pull it so I would check for a linking issue or post your

Answer (score -2):

There is a typo in your paragraph element. Change clsss to class.

Answer (score -2):

You have missspelled class. You have use `clsss` instead of `class`.
Snippet:

```
<div class="These">
  <p class="project" id="project">
    These are some of my projects
  </p>
</div>
```